# OpenID connect Successful response has # between redirect uri and access token

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, jwt, single-sign-on, openid-connect

I have setup an App in Azure Ad for Oauth 2.0 using JWT, the access token is returned successfully but the url has a hashtag(#)between the redirect URL and the access_token. Application is expecting a question mark(?) to complete the sign, so if I replace the # with ? on the address bar the sign-process completes.

Is there a way to do this from Azure App Registration itself so that the response is returned with a ? instead of #? or should I be sending the request differently?

Below is the request

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=<client_id>&response_type=token&redirect_uri=<url_encoded_redirect_uri>&scope=<scope>&response_mode=fragment&state=12345&nonce=678910
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the request, response_mode had to be form_post instead of fragment. That solved the issue

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=<client_id>&response_type=token&redirect_uri=<url_encoded_redirect_uri>&scope=<scope>&response_mode=form_post&state=12345&nonce=678910
```

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc#send-the-sign-in-request